# JS return 1st element of 2d array sorted

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting

I have following 2D array: `[["fox", "100"], ["the", "1"], ["quick", "50"]]`

And want to store only the first element of the array, but sorted based on the second value.

Desired output: `the,quick,fox`

I have written a loop that iterates over the first elements which seems to work, however I cannot get it sorted based on the second value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
  x1 += inputArr[i][0];
  if(i != inputArr.length - 1){ 
   x1 = x1 + ",";
  }
 }

  
Write(x1); //outputs -> fox,the,quick
```

Comment: My naive attempt would be `inputArr.sort((a,b) => a[1]-b[1]).map(([a]) => a).flat().join(',')` - flat might be unneeded though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort` function of Array. The `sort` function takes a lambda function with 2 inputs based on return value decides the order

```js
let arr = [["fox", "100"], ["the", "1"], ["quick", "50"]];

let output= arr.sort((a,b) => a[1]-b[1]).map(e => e[0]).join(",");
```

Comment: Whenever I saw ```"5" - "1"``` , it always shocks me.  I always use ```Number()``` or ```+``` before doing maths with js number. please note: ```"5" + "1" = "51"``` but ```"5"-"1" = 4```.

Comment: Note that `sort` manipulates the source array. Meaning `arr` will be sorted as well. This might or might not be desirable. If not, `slice` or `concat` are simple ways to make a copy before sorting.